# Jquery UI Dialog make not closable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to close when i click some button. I don't want to close when click escape or close icon. How can i do it ? i want to like this

```
$("#BtnOpen").click(function(){
$("#MyDialog").dialog("open");
});

$("#BtnClose").click(function(){
$("#MyDialog").dialog("close");
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a more complete example. What have you tried so far. How are you creating the dialog? What options are you already using? For example `closeOnEscape: false`, see more: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI's dialog allows you to disable the close on escape feature, and to avoid it closing on the default button is just a matter of hiding it in CSS.

JS:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#MyDialog" ).dialog({
      closeOnEscape: false,
      closeText: "hide",
      autoOpen: false
    });

    $("#BtnOpen").click(function(){
        $( "#MyDialog" ).dialog("open");
    });

    $("#BtnClose").click(function(){
        $( "#MyDialog" ).dialog("close");
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    display: none;
}
```

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/norim_13/xck4cnp8/).